# Add string to each row when converting json to csv with JQ

Tags: json, csv, jq

I'm trying to convert this JSON:

```
{
  "reservationSummary": {
    "pickLoc": {
      "locationCode": "EWR"
    }
  },
  "vehicleSummaryList": [
    {
      "carGroup": "Economy",
      "carClass": "A",
      "payNowRate": {
        "amount": "2327.49",
        "totalRateAmount": "3387.19"
      },
      "payLaterRate": {
        "amount": "2449.99",
        "totalRateAmount": "3540.79"
      }    },
    {
      "carGroup": "Compact",
      "carClass": "B",
      "payNowRate": {
        "amount": "2327.49",
        "totalRateAmount": "3387.19"
      },
      "payLaterRate": {
        "amount": "2449.99",
        "totalRateAmount": "3540.79"
      }    }
  ]
}
```

into a csv that looks like this:

```
EWR,A,Economy,A,3540.79
EWR,B,Compact,A,3540.79
```

NOTE: I added `EWR` (from `.reservationSummary.pickLoc.locationCode`to the 1st column of each row.

I've successfully gotten the csv without it like this:

```
jq -r '(.vehicleSummaryList[] | [.carClass, .carGroup, .carAvailability, .payLaterRate.totalRateAmount])|@csv' examle.json
```

But any attempt to add `.reservationSummary.pickLoc.locationCode` like this:

```
jq -r '.reservationSummary.pickLoc.locationCode, (.vehicleSummaryList[] | [.carClass, .carGroup, .carAvailability, .payLaterRate.totalRateAmount])|@csv' examle.json
```

gets an error like this:

```
jq: error (at examle.json:51): string ("EWR") cannot be csv-formatted, only array
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@csv` requires an array as input but `.reservationSummary.pickLoc.locationCode` only produces a string. Instead, make it an array by wrapping it into `[]` and then add the two arrays together using `+`:

```
[.reservationSummary.pickLoc.locationCode] + (
  .vehicleSummaryList[]
  | [.carClass, .carGroup, .carAvailability, .payLaterRate.totalRateAmount]
)
| @csv
```